# Optimize subquery in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, innodb

My table **schema** is as follow:

[image]

Indexes:

- *products.id PRIMARY KEY*
- *products.description UNIQUE*
- *expenses.id PRIMARY KEY*
- *expenses.product_id FOREIGN KEY to product.id*

---

My **goal** is to load

1. Cost of each product of current month **(AS costs_november)**
2. Cost of each product of last month **(AS costs_october)**
3. Change in costs of current month compared to last 
   (current month costs - last month costs) **(AS costs)**
4. Percentage change of current month costs compared to last 
   (last month costs * 100 / current month costs) **(AS percent_diff)**

---

I've managed to code SQL that does exactly that:

```sql
SELECT description, (SUM(cost) - IFNULL(
(
    SELECT SUM(cost)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE month = 9 AND year = 2019 AND product_id = e.product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
), 0)) AS costs,

SUM(cost) * 100 / 
(
    SELECT SUM(cost)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE month = 9 AND year = 2019 AND product_id = e.product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS percent_diff,

SUM(cost) AS costs_october,

IFNULL(
(
    SELECT SUM(cost)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE month = 9 AND year = 2019 AND product_id = e.product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
), 0) AS costs_september

FROM expenses e
JOIN products p ON (e.product_id = p.id)
WHERE month = 10 AND year = 2019
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_id;
```

But is copy-pasting the same subquery three times really the solution? In theory it requires to run four queries per product. Is there a more elegant way?

Appreciate for any help!

Comment: Do you never have intra month cost changes?

Comment: Please list the indexes you currently have in place.

Comment: @P.Salmon Expenses/costs won't change later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would address this with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    p.description,
    sum(case when e.month = 11 then e.cost else 0 end) costs_november,
    sum(case when e.month = 10 then e.cost else 0 end) costs_october,
    sum(case when e.month = 11 then e.cost else -1 * e.cost end) costs,
    sum(case when e.month = 10 then e.cost else 0 end)
        * 100
        / nullif(
            sum(case when e.month = 11 then e.cost else 0 end),
            0
        ) percent_diff
from expenses e
inner join products p on p.id = e.product_id
where e.year = 2019 and e.month in (10, 11)
goup by e.product_id
```

You can avoid repeating the same conditional sums by using a subquery (your RDBMS would probably optimize it anyway, but this tends to make the query more readable):

```
select 
    description,
    costs_november,
    costs_october,
    costs_november - costs_october costs,
    costs_october * 100 / nullif(costs_november, 0) percent_diff
from (
    select 
        p.description,
        sum(case when e.month = 11 then e.cost else 0 end) costs_november,
        sum(case when e.month = 10 then e.cost else 0 end) costs_october
    from expenses e
    inner join products p on p.id = e.product_id
    where e.year = 2019 and e.month in (10, 11)
    goup by e.product_id
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate for all months and all products at one time:

```
SELECT year, month,
       SUM(costs) as curr_month_costs,
       LAG(SUM(costs)) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) as prev_month_costs,
       (SUM(costs) -
        LAG(SUM(costs)) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) 
       ) as diff,
       LAG(SUM(costs)) OVER (ORDER BY year, month) * 100 / SUM(costs)
FROM expenses e JOIN
     products p
     ON e.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY product_id, year, month
ORDER BY year, month, product_id;
```

You can use a subquery if you want to select only the current month.

Comment: I guess i can't use LAG() cause i'm still using MySQL 5.7.26